# Expected a character buffer object error

Tags: python

I'm programming in Python, and I keep getting an error when I run my code:

> expected character buffer object

Any ideas/help?

```
enter code here`fd = open('Comments', 'w'
with open('Comments.txt', 'w') as f:
blockname = raw_input('what is your block? ')
f.write(blockname)
rating = input('Rating from 1 to 10 please! ')
f.write(rating)
Comments = raw_input('please write your comments on this class here ')
f.write(Comments)
f.write('                                   ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `f.write(blockname)`, `f.write(rating)`, and `f.write(Comments)` to `f.write(str(blockname))`, `f.write(str(rating))`, and `f.write(str(Comments))`

The function `write(str)` writes *the string* str to the file, so you need to convert your content to string before writing them.